# SPRING 5.2.5 and missing setTestSession() method in DefaultSftpSessionFactory

Tags: spring, sftp

I have the latest SPRING test project created and the setTestSession() method not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcvTY.jpg)

However the documentation here claims its avaiable after spring 5.1x version [https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/session/CachingSessionFactory.html#setTestSession-boolean-]